# Is it possible to do a code freeze and create a stable build in R?

Tags: r

Yesterday, I was told CRAN packages are not stable.  In otherwords, packages in CRAN can be changed and updated.  In otherwords if I execute the following today, I might not get the same version of some_package tomorrow.

```
install.packages('some_package')
```

If this is the case, how can I create a stable version of software in R and freeze the code to create a stable production release of software that uses common existing R packages?

Comment: [Packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) might help

Comment: I think the best way to do this is a docker container. Otherwise [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html) is a good option.

Comment: Clumsy but effective:  do the equivalent of `chmod 555`  on each library's subdirectory that you want locked down.  That way, any `install.packages(foo)` will not overwrite the versions you want to keep.